# How can I prevent my IP address from getting banned by Ebay?

Tags: php

I'm using the ebay API to import the products. After some days/time period I can't get the records from ebay. To ensure the problem I have requested it from the different IP. And it works from it. It concludes that ebay is not allowing the request from earlier IP. So what can be the solution?

Comment: did you try and contact ebay's support?

Comment: @In silico would you make it an answer, not comment? It perfectly answers the question.

Comment: thanks but if I would have any specific regarding help then its fine.

Answer (score 3):

You might be blacklisted. If you consume too many resources or perform too many queries in a time frame (on purpose or by accident), you're almost guaranteed to be blocked. In that case, you can contact ebay's support and try to straighten out the situation.